# How to export MySQL query result to multiple `txt` files?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

In my MySQL workbench, I have a table `color_table` -

```
Account |    ID    |  Color |
--------|----------|--------|
 A      |    1     |  Blue  |
 A      |    1     | Orange |
 A      |    1     |  Red   |
 B      |    2     | Black  |
 B      |    2     |  Blue  |
```

Is there a single query to generate `.txt` files with names A.txt and B.txt where-

```
A.txt-               

Blue        
Orange                 
Red
```

&

```
B.txt-

Black
Blue
```

This table can have as many as 7 million rows. What would you recommend as the best approach for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by first exporting the 2 columns into a file-

```
SELECT Account, Color FROM color_table
INTO OUTFILE /tmp/colors.csv
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

and then writing a Python script to iterate through `colors.csv` and generate new files as I described in the question.

But I'd still like to know if there's a way to do what I want with 1 or 2 MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running this in SQLPlus.  Spool the output to txt or perhaps csv instead.

```
Select color from table where account='A';
```

Comment: this is pretty elementary; won't help if there's 6 million rows

Comment: The task is elementary, just a big job.  You're right though.  I tried a similar operation on table with 34+ million rows.  It churned through ~90k in 40 seconds before I terminated.  It will work provided there is enough disk, but its going to take some time to complete.

Comment: also, you're hard-coding the `account='A'` part. So you'd have to know all the account names (which could be in 1000's) by a `select distinct` and then run separate queries for each of them.